# NameError: name 'rescaleFrame' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv

I just started with opencv and got the above error. I need some help

```
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('MyOutPutVideo.avi')
while True:
    isTrue,frame = capture.read()
    frame_resized = rescaleFrame(frame,scale=.2)
    cv2.imshow("video",frame)
    cv2.imshow("Video small",frame_resized)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('0'):
        break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: For the future, show what you've tried to do to solve your  problem.

Comment: You have to define that function. Search for opencv rescale frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function `rescaleFrame`:

```
Import cv2 as cv
def rescaleFrame(frame, scale):
    width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale)
    dimensions = (width, height)
    return cv.resize(frame, dimensions, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
```